# How do I get this attribute using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I know should be really simple, but I just don't get it.

I'm using clone to copy a `<li>` element:

```
var li = $('.selected_list .template').clone();
```

The list has the following items:

```
<li>
  <input type="hidden" value="" class="item_id" name="item_id[]">
  <div class="col_rating">
    <input type="textbox" value="" maxlength="3" class="item_rating" name=""> 
  </div>  
</li>
```

I can use the following to change the content of the `item_id` input:

```
  $(li).find('.item_id').prop({
    'value': $(item).attr('id'),
    'name': 'item_id[]'
  });
  $(li).find('.col_rating').find('input.col_rating').prop('name','item_rating[]');

  $(li).find('.col_name').text($(item).find(('.assoc_name')).text());
  $(li).find('.col_cost > input.item_cost').val($('.info_container .unit_cost').val());
```

But how can I change the value of the `input` that is wrapped inside the `div`?

I tried using `>` to access children, but that didn't work.

You help is much appreciated :)

**Update**
I am able to change the value of the `item_id`. The question is, how do I update the `name` attribute of the `col_rating` input?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.item_rating', li).val('250');
```

Comment: Thanks @adeneo. That worked like a charm and it simplified a lot of code. One learns something new every day :)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set an element's value. Not `.prop()`, not `.attr()`.

```
li.find('.item_id').val('250');
```

Comment: I thought, `prop()` came to remove the problem with `attr()` . Cant we still use `prop()` for setting and getting value ?

Comment: @matt-ball Using `prop` works just fine - since I'm able to change the value of the `item_id` input. I'm just not able to change the input inside the div.

Answer (score 1):

Replace the colon with a comma. Also, `li` is already a jQuery object, no need to wrap it again.

```
li.find('.item_id').prop('value', '250');
```

Actually, instead of setting the property using `.prop()`, use [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
li.find('.item_id').val('250');
```

Comment: I'm actually changing the `name` property as well. So to do it all in one go (changing multiple properties that is) I'm using `prop({})`. And what about `item_rating`?

Comment: Whats wrong with `prop` . Last time my final conclusion was 'I can use prop with any property'.

Comment: @Jashwant Nothing wrong with prop: `prop('value','250')` sets the property `value` to `250`, which causes the text field to be populated with `250`. `.val(250)` does exactely the same thing, but it looks more obvious (and needs less characters).

Answer (score 0):

```
li.find('.item_rating').val('250')
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var li = $('.selected_list .template').clone();
li
  .find('.item_id').prop({ // find item_id and change properties
    'value': '250',
    'name': 'name1'
  })
  .end() // jump to list again
  .find('.item_rating').prop({ // find .item_rating and change properties
    'value': '150',
    'name': 'name2'
  })
  .appendTo('.selected_list'); // append to list (you may have something else)
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BGK83/1/)**